# CMake find_package() search paths when cross compiling on windows

Tags: cmake

I am trying to cross compile with arm-none-eabi-gcc on windows using cmake, and for some reason find_package() is searching versions of all the directories in my $PATH and *not* the CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH I provided in the toolchain file. specifically, in the toolchain file I have the following lines:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "C:/toolchains/cm0p_root" CACHE PATH "Cmake install prefix")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
...
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

I compiled and installed my library with the same toolchain, and everything was installed correctly to the cmp0_root directory.

My projects CMakeLists.txt file has this in it:

```
find_package(myLIB REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(testProject PUBLIC myLIB::myLIB)
```

and find_package() fails to find the library. It succeeds if I put either of the two versions with HINTS or PATHS

```
find_package(myLIB REQUIRED HINTS /)
find_package(myLIB REQUIRED PATHS "C:/toolchains/cm0p_root")
```

and using the command line option `-D CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON` I can see it is searhcing the following paths:

```
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/git-sdk-64/mingw64/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/Users/myname/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/Program Files/ConEmu/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/Python/Python36-32/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/Python/Python36-32/Scripts/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/Windows/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/LLVM/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 8.0/common/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 8.0/avr/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 8.2/arm/]
Checking prefix [C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/Bin/]
```

and many more, but it is clear that CMake is prefixing the FIND_ROOT_PATH to the beginning of all my windows $PATH variables! the list is a lot longer but it never searches `C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/` which is what I need (I guess why the hint works).

How do I get CMake to not search all these directories? I am cross compiling, and as far as I know it should only be searching my "fake" root directory since `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE` is set to `ONLY`

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` denotes **root** directory for search, but actual **prefixes** are computed by *appending* to root directory some subdirectories. You may find algorithm of computing prefix in the [find_package documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_package.html). By default, CMake doesn't search under `/` subdirectory, so your root directory doesn't interpreted by CMake as a search prefix. You add `/` to the variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, so your **root** path will be also treated as a **prefix**.

Comment: I was confusing the `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and <prefix>, thinking that the root path was used as the prefix in the search paths from the documentation. Re-reading it after your comment it makes a lot more sense.


so a better toolchain snippet would add the line:
`set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH /)` ?


I used `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH` since it seems better for a toolchain file, the docs say that `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is supposed to be set in the project.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure what is the intended usage of variable `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`, but according to its documentation, it looks like to be exactly for a toolchain. BTW, why do you install your program **exactly** into the root directory? It is like you install something into `C:/`. Usually, on Windows `C:/Program Files/<program-name>` is used as an install prefix. What is OS for which you are cross-compiling?

Comment: I am not installing directly into the root, but using the _GNUInstallDirs_ module. so headers are put into `C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/include`, libraries into `C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/lib`, cmake config files to `C:/toolchains/cm0p_root/share/<name>*/` and so on.

I am cross compiling for bare metal ARM cortex and AVRs. I am hoping to use a "sysroot" where I can install packages to, so that I don't need huge monolithic source trees. For example a simple real time scheduler I use needs to be replicated in every source tree, but it would be nice to compile and "install" it once per architecture.

Comment: Yes, on Linux-like OS using `GNUInstallDirs` with the install prefix `/` has much more sense. I am not really sure, but CMake would be wise to not use Windows way for construct prefixes, when it cross-compiles for Linux. You are setting up proper `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` in your toolchain, don't you?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)` and `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR cortex-m0plus)` which should set `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING` to true. but again, _not_ compiling for linux, just a bare metal device. Maybe internally is constructs prefixes in the windows way unless is is explicitly set to linux. This seems like a bad idea since most bare metal toolchains I know of use the gnu folder structure (even on windows).

Comment: @Tsyvarev  pretty simple solution, but you answered the question. Do you want to write it as an answer? I'll ask in the cmake mailing list about the strange prefix construction on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Creating an answer from the comment by Tsyvarev*

The variable `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` denotes root directory for search, but actual prefixes are computed by appending directories to root directory. The exact implementation of this can be found in the [find package search procedure documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/find_package.html#search-procedure).

**The relevant steps are the first two (from CMake docs):**

> 1. Search paths specified in the `<PackageName>_ROOT` CMake variable and the `<PackageName>_ROOT` environment variable, where `<PackageName>` is the package to be found. The package root variables are maintained as a stack so if called from within a find module, root paths from the parent’s find module will also be searched after paths for the current package. This can be skipped if `NO_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH` is passed or by setting the
> 2. Search paths specified in cmake-specific cache variables. These are intended to be used on the command line with a `-DVAR=value`. The values are interpreted as semicolon-separated lists. This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_PATH` is passed or by setting the `CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH` to `FALSE`:
>
>    - `MAKE_PREFIX_PATH`
>    - `CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH`
>    - `CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH`

The variable we care about is [`MAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) which is initialized with the value of [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH.html):

> Semicolon-separated list of directories specifying installation prefixes to be searched by the find_package(), find_program(), find_library(), find_file(), and find_path() commands. Each command will add appropriate subdirectories (like bin, lib, or include) as specified in its own documentation.

So a better toolchain for this purpose would clear out the values in `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`, for example:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "C:/toolchains/cm0p_root" CACHE PATH "Cmake install prefix")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH /)
...
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

*A note on if this **should** be done:*
This technique did not really pan out. It is hard to maintain as you would need a separate "sysroot" for each non-compatible combination of compile options. Instead, at least for now, I am using [Conan](https://conan.io/) to cache and consume pre-compiled dependencies. For smaller things I just use [CPM](https://github.com/TheLartians/CPM.cmake) which is a nice wrapper around the native CMake [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/module/FetchContent.html) module